# Data passed as props is not shown in django and reactjs

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

I wanted to pass if username is authenticated or not from django template inside script tag which renders data for reactjs page so that i can use react router for routing user to login or logout. For this i did as below but no luck . I could not fetch value using this.props inside my react page.I get an error in console as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isUserAuthenticated' of undefined". What have i done wrong ? Sorry for my english if i could not explain clearly . I hope my code might enlighten you what I am trying to do.

**index.html**

```
{% load  staticfiles future i18n account rental_tags %}
    <div id="homepage">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'build/js/app.js'%}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var data = {
            isUserAuthenticated:{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}true{% else %}false{% endif %}
        };

    $(function() {

      app.showHomePage("homepage",data);
    });

    </script>
```

index.js(entry point for webpack)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Homepage from 'homepage/Homepage';

 window.app = {
        showHomePage: function(id,data){
        ReactDOM.render(
          <Homepage />, document.getElementById(id,data)
        );
}
```

**Homepage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Body from './components/Body';
class Homepage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.data.isUserAuthenticated);
    return (
            <div className="layer">
              <Navbar />
              <Body />
            </div>
      );
  }
}

export default Homepage;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting the prop to show up on your `Homepage` component as `this.props.data.isAuthenticated`, but you're not passing any props to the component when you render it.

You need to pass the `data` parameter from the `showHomepage` method.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Homepage data={data}/>,
  document.getElementById(id)
);
```

You can also remove the second argument to `document.getElementById` (which only accepts one).

Comment: My bad i forgot to pass the data as props in my Homepage component. Thanks for your help. I feel pity for me :) .